# read data from a curl request in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, curl

I'm working on an API , I send a data array in Json that looks like :

```
$data = ["id" => "1212", 
         "name"   => 'anas',
         "items"  => ['item1','item2','item3']
        ];
```

to an action in laravel , when I try to read values using Input::get , I could read the value of id , but name returns null .

When I execute the Input::all() , it shows that all fields are there with their values. So I think the problem is related to String. But , when I do a var_dump , it shows string type for all fields.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `dd(Input::all())` and is this 4.2 or 5?

Comment: array(6) { ["email"]=> string(20) "yychen@systemedia.de" ["token"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$e19B//3pI3E5fozPt8RQgeJ06goB.jwn.KU9EH0qioi5C.kuq6Z6a" ["items"]=> array(2) { ["sku"]=> string(9) "chess-003" ["q"]=> int(3) } ["order"]=> string(3) "777" ["s"]=> string(4) "shop" ["h"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" }